# How to add/remove fields from a form type depending on the action

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have two actions that are instantiating a form type.

I need to add/remove fields from the form type depending on the action from which the form type is instantiated.

How can I do this? should I extend the form to get two form types? or use the form events maybe?